# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error using web socket connection

Tags: websocket

I have a website with laravel and node.js and websocket connection on my pages with express server. when I use my website after a time range between 1 to 2 hours I receive DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error, I clean all browser cache, windows cache, Ip cache and test all the solutions ralated to this error, I changed my domain registrar but no result. I called my ISP and they did something like resetting my ip, it was solved just for 2 hours and again no result. my server is linux in hetzner. I have other domains and website on the same server with websocket but no problem with that! I got confused . thanks for helping .